# If I know a keybinding/shortcut, how to get the corresponding function?

Tags: key-bindings, help

I want to use the function to switch to other window when there are only 2 windows in emacs.  I know that the shortcut is `C-x o`, but I don't know which function that shortcut calls.

**How do I determine the mapping between shortcut and function?**

Answer (score 22):

The `describe-key` command (`C-h k`) will tell you what command is bound to a given key sequence. To go the other way and find out what keys (if any) are bound to a command, use `where-is` (`C-h w`).

You can list all available key bindings using `describe-bindings` (`C-h b`).

As of Emacs 25, you can also use `view-lossage` (`C-h l`) to see the recent history of every key typed and the corresponding commands that were executed.

You'll notice these commands are all bound to the help map (`C-h`). You might want to try `C-h C-h` to see all the available help commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just got it, I could use the function `describe-bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `helm`, you can try `helm-descbinds`. It's pretty convenient, when you want to define your own bindings instead of using the preconfigured shortcuts.